# Making a Tree using Turtle (That is right side up)

Tags: python, tree, turtle-graphics

This is my first time ever using turtle, so bear with me. I am suppose to make a tree diagram in python using turtle. I made the tree and it looks perfect except for one problem, which might seem really simple but, when I print out my tree it looks like this.

[image]

So what would I add to make my tree right side up? Here is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()


def tree(length = 100):

    if length < 10:
        return
    t.forward(length)
    t.left(30)
    tree(length *.7)
    t.right(60)
    tree(length * .7)
    t.left(30)
    t.backward(length)
    return


tree()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Just turn the turtle before starting your tree.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: Not in the function because it's recursive. Globally, right before you call the tree function.

Comment: Do that by adding `t.left(90)` right after `t = turtle.Turtle()`, before defining `tree`.

Comment: I didn't load new comments fast enough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remember that the function is recursive, thus you need to turn the turtle outside of the function. You can use a function in a function, but I would just turn the turtle in the global scope right before you call the function:

```
t.left(90) # then call tree after with tree()
```